# Deploy website on Firebase Hosting with specific path

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting

I have my own domain i.e [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and I just connected with Firebase Hosting, however what I want is to deploy a website (using Flutter) for that domain and a different one with the following path: [www.example.com/other](http://www.example.com/other), as you can see the /other should direct to another website that I have, is that possible throw Firebase Hosting? or do I need to have two domains one for each website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting only deploys a single site in its entirety, using all of the content in a single folder, usually called "public" in your project.  It doesn't really do partial updates scoped to a specific path.

You can certainly deploy multiple apps to one site.  You will just have to make sure all of their content is added to that public folder for deployment as a unit.  If you don't want to do that, you can certainly manage each site independently with a different hostname for each.